# The [guidance] tag needs to be guided to destruction

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request, clean-up

[guidance](/questions/tagged/guidance) has **47** questions.

They are almost universally **opinion-based** and thus off-topic and closable.

Some can be saved through editing, but those are the minority.

Your task, should you choose to accept it:

- Vote to close questions that should be closed.
- Improve questions that don't need to be closed.

*Do not remove the tag yet!*  We need it for collaborative cleanup.

Comment: This is my favorite one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782131/need-guidance-for-my-first-android-application-how-many-activities-should-i-use

Comment: @Jamal This one is way better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458384/am-i-gooing-in-rigth-direction

Comment: @JoshC: *Just* [guidance] and also a funny title?  LOL.  You win!

Comment: Cleaned up a few of the obvious ones and then ended up in the [tag:productivity] tag and... oh my...

Comment: You guys have all the fun. :/ And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199/what-makes-you-lose-motivation) looks like a gem.

Comment: @animuson, I don't think anyone would blame you for a bit of, uh, selective question genocide there.

Comment: Zero questions left, now this tag can quietly walk into obscurity.

Comment: @animuson: Tag is nuked.  Poke Oded and ask him to blacklist.  And you can put a [meta-tag:status-completed] on this one.  I'll forego the funny pic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [Won't won't post a funny pic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210724/the-guidance-tag-needs-to-be-guided-to-destruction#comment676540_210724), I suppose I'll have to make a meager effort.

[image: Deal with it? No, I think you meant DEALT with it. Where are my damned sunglasses?]

The tag has been cleansed and the questions purged.  Thanks, everyone!

Comment: *breathes in the fresh air*